# how to boost telegram channel with python(telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

in telegram it is now possible to boost channels. how can this be done using python, preferably telethon?

example link for channel boost: https://t.me/ApeCryptor?boost

[image]

Comment: This question needs to be improved. What have you tried? Did you read any documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- uninstall telethon ( `pip uninstall telethon` )

2- install last Layer ( `pip install -U https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/archive/v1.zip` )

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

username = 'username'

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.stories.ApplyBoostRequest(username))
    print(result)
```